# Trying to read unzipped FASTQ file using shortRead package and readFastq function

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, fastq

I am trying to read the fastq files using following function:

```
library("ShortRead") #Bioconductor

readFastq('C://Users//Durdona//Documents//BAL_1_S3_L001_I1_001', pattern=character(0))
```

However it showing up the following output:

```
Error: Input/Output
no input files found
dirPath: C://Users//Durdona//Documents//BAL_1_S3_L001_I1_001
pattern: character(0)
```

I double checked the pathway, tried to move the file and change the directory pathway, still the same thing. How could I read FAST Q file just to see the output?

Comment: Maybe the slashes are wrong direction: `C:\\Users\\Durdona\\Documents\\BAL_1_S3_L001_I1_001`.

Comment: What is the output of `list.files("C://Users//Durdona//Documents//BAL_1_S3_L001_I1_001")` ?